# Display custom attributes, but not in default tab

Tags: attributes, product-view

Magento shows custom attributes in the first tab after product main information.

Inside this tab I have some custom attributes that I would like to show in other place of the page (under sku for example).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to disable the *show in frontend* in Magento admin `Catalog / Attributes / Manage attributes` -> edit attribute -> disable the option.
This way it will not show up in the default tab.

If you want to add it for instance with the `sku` add it in the template `app/design/frontend/{TEMPLATE}/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

Sku

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>
```

Custom attribute

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getMyCustomAttribute(), 'my_custom_attribute') ?>
```

Comment: Jeroen, any idea what the "Used in Product Listing" option does?

Comment: If the custom attribute code above doesn't work for you in v2.2.1, try this code instead: `$_product = $block->getProduct();
$value = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('my_custom_attribute')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);`